# Is there a way to bypass having to declare each individual cell of WPF UniformGrid by making a cell template?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display the same content in each cell of UniformGrid, so that it looks like this:[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG4sG.png)

This code does that:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="600" Height="600">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Label"/>
        </Style>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>

    <!-- 16 Canvas declarations -->
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
</UniformGrid>
```

But I would like to do it without repeating this part of the code for each cell:

```
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle/>
        <Label/>
    </Canvas>
```

It seems repetitive to write it 16 times and I feel like there's probably a shorter way. I've looked for a way to make a template for UniformGrid and have only found posts mentioning using ItemsControl. I tried implementing it like this:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Rectangle/>
                <Label/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="600" Height="600">
                <UniformGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="100"/>
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Label"/>
                    </Style>
                </UniformGrid.Resources>
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

But then nothing showed on screen. Some posts said that there is no way to make a template for a Grid type control. Is there even a way to make a template like this for a UniformGrid?

Comment: You need some items. Bind a list or observablecollection of viewmodels to the itemssource is the usual approach. Simpler to aply the values to properties in the template rather than as a style.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! You could post an answer so I could mark it as accepted.